# cant change app launcher grid in settings/tweak

Tags: applications, apps, launcher

I'd like to extend my app launcher grid and I saw some videos where people do it by installing tweak and changing the grid under launcher.

I followed this guide https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/improve-elementary-oss-quick-launcher/

tweak appears in settings, even installed an osx theme but the grid option doesnt show up, only show category by default is there

it's a fresh install of 5.1 and first time using linux. other things I did were just install chrome and osx theme

Comment: Try dconf editor, Maybe it has something might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option of custom columns and rows is removed from the slingshot - that's why it is not in dconf editor neighter elementary-tweaks anymore. There are few closed issues on that into github and the new ones appear, but the team is working on another approach wich do not include these keys anymore.

The only way I know to achieve this functionality now is to **downgrade the slingshot, which is not recommended**, but this is what I did because I really miss a bigger apps grid. There is a guide how to achieve this on https://hastebin.atvg-studios.com/dobamidivi.txt it works flowlessly at the moment, but probably it will brake with the next update of the slingshot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that `elementary-tweaks` no longer has this option. I couldn't find it in `dconf-editor` either (though this was an excellent idea @Raj).

Many Linux desktop environments are more tweakable than elementary's Pantheon system, and if tweaking is important to you, check them out! My advice would be to live with the workflow elementary gives you without tweaking it too much, though. I think you'll like what you'll find when you stop worrying about futzing with it. : )